# unexpected token using es6 map()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Is there anything wrong with my code below?

```
render(){
    return (
      var users= this.state.users.map(user => 
        <li key={user.id}>user.name</li>
      )
      <ul>{users}</ul>
    )
  }
```

I get error: unexpected token.

Comment: There's a typo in your closing `</ul>` tag, you typed `</u>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what you're returning in your code. Either do all logic above your `return` call, as shown below, or do like Ori Drori does in their answer.

```
render() {
      var users= this.state.users.map(user => 
        <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
      );

      return <ul>{users}</ul>;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`render()` should return only a single element:

```
render(){
  return (
    <ul>
    {
      this.state.users.map(user => (
        <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
      )
    }
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: ouch, forget bout that

Comment: but means i can't assign loop to a variable?

Comment: Sure you can - see @Chris's answer.

Comment: I believe it should be `<li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>`.